# How do I bind a command to a class above it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Good day to all.

First of all, I am using the MVVM pattern and I have the following problem.
I have a Main UserControl in which there is a ContentControl and a button.
This button changes the content of the ContentControl "LoadSecondVMCommand".
In the then loaded UserControl (Second UserControl) there is a Back-Button, which should then access the command LoadFirstVMCommand,
to load the FirstViewModel again. So I have to be able to access the LoadFirstVMCommand in the MainUserControl class from the Second UserControl somehow.
How do I make the binding or how do I solve it, that I can change the ContentControlView from the Second UserControl.

```
//Main UserControl

<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding LoadSecondVMVMCommand}">Load</Button>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding ContentControlView}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

namespace ViewModels
{
    public class MainUserControl : ObservableObject
    {
        private object _contentControlView;
        public object ContentControlView
        {
            get { return _devicesView; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _devicesView, value); }
        }

        public ICommand LoadFirstVMCommand { get; private set; }
        public ICommand LoadSecondVMCommand { get; private set; }

        public DeviceViewModel()
        {
            LoadFirstVMCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadFirstVM);
            LoadSecondVMCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadSecondVM);
            ContentControlView = new FirstViewModel();
        }

        private void LoadFirstVM()
        {
            ContentControlView = new FirstViewModel();
        }

        private void LoadSecondVM()
        { 
            ContentControlView = new SecondViewModel();
        }
    }
}

//Second UserControl

<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Button>Back</Button> //this button should access the Command LoadFirstVMCommand in class MainUserControl to LoadFirstVM
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The exact answer depends on the implementation details of the View and the passing of the Data Context to it.
Most likely the MainUserControl instance is in the Data Context of the Window.
In this case, you need to set the pop-up binding by the container type in the button: `Command="{Binding DataContext.LoadFirstVMCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void LoadSecondVM()
{
    ContentControlView = new SecondViewModel(LoadFirstVMCommand);
}
    ...
```

ctor of SecondViewModel:

```
public SecondViewModel(ICommand backCommand)
{
    this.BackCommand = backCommand;
}
```